# Randomize lines inside a master shell script for every iteration

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a master script master_script.sh, which has several scripts inside it.

```
    Inside Master_script.sh
    
    ./script1.sh
    ./script2.sh
    ./script3.sh
    ..
    ..
    ./script10.sh
```

I execute master script from terminal using ./Master_Script.sh. I need to run infinitely
Master_script and randomize the sub-scripts order inside Master script such that every iteration of Master_script would randomize the order of execution of scripts .

```
Ex
Iteration1
./script1.sh
./script3.sh
./script5.sh
..
..
Iteration2
./script2.sh
./script1.sh
./script9.sh
..
..
etc
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "infinitely" and can you confirm all scripts need to run in random order each time the master script is run. (It is no doubt doable but it would be a lot easier to have a single script which runs forever randomly picking scripts to run)

Comment: That should be fine. yes..I need to run in random order each time the master script is run..

Comment: Unfortunately you did not actually answer either of my questions.  So again, asked slightly differently  - question 1 - what do you mean by "indefinately".  question 2 - Do you need to run through all the scripts before repeating the random cycle (which is a lot harder then continually randomly picking a script to run)

Comment: I am sorry about my last comment.. 1.) I need to run master script in a while ( 1 ) loop i.e execute it continously 2.) Yes I need to run through all scripts before next iteration begins and next iteration would execute all scripts in a random manner ..So my take is to  randomize all the lines in a master script before its next iteration, but not sure how to accomplisht this

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is a command called "shuf" (which I'd not heard of until today).   shuf takes input and randomly rearranges the output.

My script loops repeatedly.   You could get rid of the while loop if you only want to run the script once.

Modify SCRIPTLIST to include all the scripts you want to run.

```
#! /bin/bash

SCRIPTLIST="./script1.sh ./script2.sh ./script3.sh ./script4.sh"

while [ 1 ]
do
        for each in `shuf -e $SCRIPTLIST`
        do
                $each
        done
done
```

Comment: Excellent..Thanks a lot..This helps..